# python pandas renaming column name startswith

Tags: python, pandas, rename, wildcard, startswith

i have multiple excel files with uniform column names, except for one.

One file calls it EndOfMarchStatus, another file calls it EndofAprilStatus, and so on.

i need to change the column name to just say EndofMonthStatus.  there really is no answer i could find that matches this question.

some form of rename command with wildcards or startswith will probably work.

things i've tried but did not work are:

```
sheet1df.columns.str.replace('Endof.*', 'EndOfMonthStatus')

sheet1df.rename(columns={sheet1df.filter(regex='*.Status').columns[0]: 'EndOfMonthStatus'}, inplace=True)

sheet1df.rename(columns={'^Status':'EndOfMonthStatus'}, inplace=True)

sheet1df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Endof%', 'EndOfMonthStatus'), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(?<=EndOf)(\w+)(?=Status)', 'Month')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "EndOfApril":[2,3,4]})
df.rename(columns = { i: "EndOfMonth" for i in  df.columns if i.startswith("EndOf") } )
```

outputs:

```
    A   EndOfMonth
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
```